# Vue JS - v-html <nuxt-link> can't use

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, router, nuxt-link

I want to use  with v-html. I create dynamic content. Like this:

```
ekspresKeno: {
      title: "Necə Oynanılır?",
      image: "/keno/ekspres-keno-popup.jpg",
      content: `
        <p>Azərbaycanda ilk dəfə dünya üzrə məşhur Keno oyunları!</p>
        <p>Keno oyunlarını ən azı 1 AZN, ən çoxu isə 1000 AZN olmaqla istənilən vaxt oyanaya bilərsiniz. Maksimal uduş məbləği isə 100 000 AZN-dir. </p>
        <p><strong>VACİB:</strong> Təsadüfi Nömrələrin Generasiyası vasitəsi ilə nömrələnmiş nömrələrdən təsadüfi şəkildə bəziləri təyin olunur və bu nömrələr əsasında uduş kombinasiyaları təyin olunur.</p>
        <p>Daha çox məlumat və bütün oyun qaydaları üçün <nuxt-link :to="$store.state.PAGES.FAQ">Yardım</nuxt-link> bölmesine bakın. </p>
      `
    }
```

And i send this **ekspresKeno** object as a props. And use it with v-html directive like this:

```
<div class="content" v-html="item.content"></div>
```

v-html can't render . Also v-html can't render @click event. How can i use  in this case.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-grass-lw78de?file=/components/Tutorial.vue

Comment: Can you share your component? How do you send your prop to component?

Comment: `v-html can't render`, can you please be more exhaustive here? What is not working? Also, do you have a [repro]?

Comment: I added codesandbox link. I want use nuxt-link with v-html but its not rendered

Answer (score 0):

When 'content' is a prop than you need to use:

```
<div class="content" v-html="props.content"></div>
```